# range(1:len(df)) assigns NaN to last rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, printing

I have this weird problem with my code . I am trying to generate Auto Id to my dataframe with this code

```
df['id'] = pd.Series(range(1,(len(df)+1))).astype(str).apply('{:0>8}'.format
```

now, len(df) is equals to 799734
but df['id'] is Nan after row 77998

I tried to print the values using:

`[print(i) for i in range(1,(len(df)+1))]`

In first attempt it printed None after 77998 values. In second attempt it printed all values to the end normally. but dataframe has still Nan in last rows.

May be it has something to do with memory? I am not getting any hint. Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing values means there is different index values in `Series` and `DataFrame`, for correct working need same.

So need pass `df.index` to `Series` constructor:

```
df['id'] = pd.Series(range(1,(len(df)+1)), index=df.index).astype(str).apply('{:0>8}'.format
```

Or 2 rows solution with assign `range`:

```
df['id'] = range(1,(len(df)+1))
df['id'] = df['id'].astype(str).apply('{:0>8}'.format
```

Or create default index values in DataFrame for same like `Series`:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df['id'] = pd.Series(range(1,(len(df)+1))).astype(str).apply('{:0>8}'.format
```